# Difficulty of solving $Ax=b$ in terms of limiting spectral density of $A$?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, mp.mathematical-physics, oc.optimization-and-control, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a random real-valued $n\times n$ matrix and we want to know the difficulty of solving $Ax=b$ when entries of $b$ are sampled IID from Normal$(0,1)$.

Can we say anything about the difficulty of solving this problem using Conjugate Gradient in terms of limiting spectral density of $A$ as $n\to \infty$?

For gradient descent applied to minimize $\|Ax-b\|^2$, we can say that the loss after $t$ iterates of gradient descent behaves as $\sim \frac{1}{t^{p+2}}$ when the density of squared singular values of $A$ is $\sim x^p$ (more precise statement [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43128/stable-alternatives-to-condition-number)). I'm looking to extend this type of characterization to other solvers.

The most relevant work I found is Tom Trogdon's, summarized in Random Matrix Theory [tutorial](https://random-matrix-learning.github.io/pdf/part3.pdf), giving some convergence results for CG on random matrices. However these are in terms of condition number, so they don't apply to $n\to \infty$ case.

Comment: You want the 'effective dimension' in both cases (for CG and for SGD), and the $n\to\infty$ case is more often tackled in the kernel/GP community (at least from a statistical viewpoint, perhaps slightly different than what you're asking for here), e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5839

Comment: @Oxonon thanks for the reference, this seems similar to "alpha-capacity" results of Berthier [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.08212.pdf), I suspect it's connected -- as "intrinsic dimensionality" is linked to the rate of eigenvalue decay, Berthier gives the link